# Office Add in to control send appointment functionality

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-addins, office365-apps, javascript-api-for-office

In office365,

Once user move appointment from one time to another, appointment gets edited. Can we control edited appointment's send button through some office add in? Is there any way to force user to use add in instead of clicking on send button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, Add-Ins should be used to extend Office functionalities but not to control existing outlook or any office app feature.